# Length of longest non-repeating substring challenge using sliding window

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working on Leetcode challenge #3 (https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/)

Here is my solution using sliding window and a dictionary. I specifically added `start = seen[s[i]]+1` to skip ahead. I am still told I am far slower than most people (for example, given `abcdefgdabc`, I am skipping `abc` when I see the second `d`. I thought this would save ton of time, but apparently this algorithm has a poor run time.

```
 class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        seen = {}
        start = 0
        max_size = 0

        # check whether left pointer has reached the end yet
        while start < len(s):
            size = 0
            for i in range(start, len(s)):
                if s[i] in seen:
                    start = seen[s[i]]+1
                    seen = {}
                    break
                else:
                    seen[s[i]] = i
                    size += 1
            max_size = max(size, max_size)
        return max_size
```

---

*UPDATE*

```
    i = 0
    j = 0
    seen = {}
    max_length = 0

    while j < len(s):
        if s[j] not in seen:
            seen[s[j]] = j
            j += 1
            max_length = max(max_length, j-i)
        else:
            i = j = seen[s[j]] + 1
            seen = {}
    return max_length
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this loop, `while start < len(s):`, the string `s` is not changing, so the length of the string is not going to change either.  Yet, for each iteration, you will evaluate `len(s)` in order to evaluate the loop condition.  `len(s)` is undoubtably a fast operation, but you should still cache the result to avoid the function call every iteration.

```
limit = len(s)
while start < limit:
    # ...
```

---

The loop `for i in range(start, len(s)):`, you are again calling `len(s)` for each iteration (of the outer loop).  You could replace this with `for i in range(start, limit):`, but we will still have a different issue...

You are (mostly) not using `i` inside the loop; you are using `s[i]`.  And you look up the character `s[i]` in 3 different places inside the loop.  Instead of looping over the indices, and looking up the character at the index, you should directly loop over the characters of the string.

```
for ch in s[start:]:
    # ...
```

Except for that pesky `seen[...] = i` statement.  You still want the index.  The `enumerate()` function can be used to count as you are looping:

```
for i, ch in enumerate(s[start:], start):
    if ch in seen:
       start = seen[ch]+1
       seen = {}
       break
    else:
       seen[ch] = i
       size += 1
```

---

### Hint

When scanning the string `abcdefgdhijklmn`, after encountering the second `d`, you reset to the character after the first `d`, and continue your scan.  But ...

Do you have to?  Aren’t all the characters between the first `d` and the second `d` unique?  Is there any way you could preserve that information, and continue on, without needing to restart with the `e`?  Maybe you don’t need nested loops!

Comment: Thank you. I rewrote the code (the len stuff I didn't to make the code slightly shorter FOR NOW, but good points). WDYT? The runtime is way better.